# Stroke-dashoffset and dasharray animations not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to animate a path line in D3.  I can get other transitions to work such as a fade in effect, but after researching how to transition paths, it seems the best option is to play with the stroke dasharray by modifying it

```js
var data = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "name": "Test Drive for data ",
      "time": "2018-04-03T01:48:51Z",
      "coordTimes": []
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "LineString",
      "coordinates": [
        [10, 10, 10],
        [30, 40, 10],
        [50, 20, 10],
        [70, 100, 10],
        [90, 20, 10],
        [110, 120, 10],
        [130, 100, 10],
        [150, 80, 10]
      ]
    }
  }]
}

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 1000)
  .attr("height", 1000);

var lineFunction = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return d[0]
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return d[1]
  })
  .curve(d3.curveBasis);

var totalLength = d3.line(data).length;

var tripLine = svg.append("path")
  .datum(data.features[0].geometry.coordinates)
  .attr("id", "pathLine")
  .style("stroke-dasharray", 0)
  .attr("d", lineFunction)
  .style("stroke", "#ddd")
  .transition()
  .duration(2000)
  .style("stroke", "red")
  .style("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
  .attr("stroke-width", 4)
  .attr("fill", "none");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

The problem is that D3 has made using prior examples extremely difficult due to updates made to the syntax that makes getting the total length of the path impossible.

Comment: *"The problem is that D3 has made using prior examples extremely difficult due to updates made to the syntax that makes getting the total length of the path impossible."* Nope, nothing has changed, since this has little to do with D3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a basic mistake here: `d3.line(data).length`, which by the way is the same of `d3.line().length`, will return 1.

The method you want is [getTotalLength](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGPathElement/getTotalLength), which has to be called on the **SVG element**, not on the D3 selection and even less on the line generator.

Therefore:

```
var totalLength = tripLine.node().getTotalLength();
```

Here is the updated code:

```js
var data = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "name": "Test Drive for data ",
      "time": "2018-04-03T01:48:51Z",
      "coordTimes": []
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "LineString",
      "coordinates": [
        [10, 10, 10],
        [30, 40, 10],
        [50, 20, 10],
        [70, 100, 10],
        [90, 20, 10],
        [110, 120, 10],
        [130, 100, 10],
        [150, 80, 10]
      ]
    }
  }]
}

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 1000)
  .attr("height", 1000);

var lineFunction = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return d[0]
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return d[1]
  })
  .curve(d3.curveBasis);

var tripLine = svg.append("path")
  .datum(data.features[0].geometry.coordinates)
  .attr("id", "pathLine")
  .style("stroke-dasharray", 0)
  .attr("d", lineFunction)
  .style("stroke", "#ddd")
  .attr("fill", "none");

var totalLength = tripLine.node().getTotalLength();

tripLine.transition()
  .duration(2000)
  .style("stroke", "red")
  .style("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
  .attr("stroke-width", 4);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```