# Basic d3 polyline flash-shape svg animation

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I would like to create a flash-shaped polyline drawing with **animation** using d3.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stroke-dashoffset and dasharray animations not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49893977/stroke-dashoffset-and-dasharray-animations-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to put the pieces together. I used [this tutorial](http://bl.ocks.org/duopixel/4063326), just my solution is based on coordinates not on dataset.

**html**

```
<script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v2.js'></script>
<svg
  width="100"
  height="100"
  id="flash"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
</svg>
```

**css**

```
path {
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2;
  fill: none;
}
```

**js**

```
var svg = d3.select("#flash");

var coords = [
  {x: 10, y: 0},
  {x: 30, y: 30},
  {x: 15, y: 30},
  {x: 50, y: 80}
]

var line = d3.svg.line()
  .interpolate("linear")
  .x(c => c.x)
  .y(c => c.y)

var path = svg.append("path")
  .attr("d", line(coords))

var totalLength = path.node().getTotalLength();

path
  .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
  .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
  .transition()
  .duration(2000)
  .ease("linear")
  .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
```

Working [Codepen](https://codepen.io/gazdagergo/pen/GXpYWB).

Comment: Is this the answer or an addition of the question? You can **edit** questions and delete answers.

Comment: No, I posted a question+answer together to share my findings.

Comment: I followed [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) how to do something like this.

Comment: What is the use of asking a question and immediately post the answer to something that has been asked and answered several times here on SO. Or is there still a question, then this in not an answer but additional information on the question

Comment: If it is duplicate, flag it pls as duplicate.

Comment: I don't have the rep do this yet. Search for `stroke-dasharray`  here on SO. A few weeks back, answered by Gerardo.

Comment: Gerardo has answered a question on `2018-08-17 05:31:54Z` and the words `line` and `animation` are part of the title, and he has answered it also on `2018-04-18 08:43:46Z`.

Comment: Ok, found it. It turned to a one-man show now. I asked, answered and even flagged as duplicate by my own.